# how to display data via php and MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have multiple infomation boxes and I'm using purely html, css and jQuery to display them. However updating or editing them is extremely time consuming, as it means rewriting every information box each time an edit or update has to be made. Therefore, I'm trying to set it up on the server side, I think i'm trying to create a loop through a PHP array containing data returned from MySQL. But I'm not sure. If anyone has a better solution for displaying please do correct me.

Example of the Information Boxes here [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0o50f9qm/5/)

Example code of a Information box

```
<div class="pin" id="pin8"><!-- VAC CARD -->
 <div class="pull-right intrest-box">
   <input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="c8" id="like8"> </div>
<p class="pull-left">05.02.16 </p><!--DATE -->
   <h1 class="text-left"> write in here </h1><!-- JOB TITLE -->
   <p><b>INFO:</b> write in here <br><!-- COMPANY NAME -->
   <b>INFO:</b>
   <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
   <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
   <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
   <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
   <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
   </p>
   <div class="text-center">
  <div class="hidden">INFO</div>
<p class="card-title"><a target="_blank" href=" paste link in here " class="">Click</a></p><!-- link to job-->
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help is genuinely appreciated. Apologies if I'm using any incorrect terminologies, I'm trying to learn them.

Comment: @PathikVejani Yes, how would that look or where can I learn how to do it?

Comment: check this https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm

Comment: Very useful link thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
<div class="pinGridWrapper">

  <?php foreach ($data as $value) { ?>
  <div class="pin" id="pin10">
    <div class="pull-right intrest-box">
      <input type="checkbox" class="faChkRnd" name="c10" id="like10"> </div>
      <p class="pull-left"><?php echo $value['date']; ?></p>
      <h1 class="text-left"> <?php echo $value['job_title']; ?> </h1>
      <p><b>INFO:</b><?php echo $value['company_name']; ?><br>
        <b>INFO:</b>
        <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
        <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
        <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
        <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
        <br>&#149; Paste a info here.
      </p>
      <div class="text-center">
        <div class="hidden">INFO</div>
        <p class="card-title"><a target="_blank" href=" paste link in here " class="">CLick</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Great! I see how that could work, you just have a database and echo out the results, but how can you add more information cards without it displaying the same data?

Comment: where is info cards? @Kez

Comment: what do you mean where? :) I think I answered my own question, if I have a info card ID and auto increment it, then get the data by ID. would that work?

Comment: @Kez what do you want to say, i am not getting

Comment: @Kez what is this: *but how can you add more information cards without it displaying the same data?*

Comment: Just to clarify I would only need the code above once as it will create the same for each row in the database right?

Comment: it will get printed column which you have used in `$value['']`

Comment: No. it will print different as you want